# node inspector can not work without specify port

Tags: node.js, node-inspector, node-debugger

I am new to node. I try to create an HTTP server that receives only POST requests and converts incoming POST body characters to upper-case and returns it to the client. And my server listen on the port provided by the first argument to your program.

### my code:

this following is my code:

```
var map = require('through2-map');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    debugger;
  console.log("typeof req");
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    req.pipe(map(function (chunk) {
      return chunk.toString().toUpperCase();
    })).pipe(res);
  }
}).listen(process.argv[2]);
```

**this program expect an port argument from command line.**

### Without debug:

I run the server: `$ node http_uppercaserer.js 8080`

And test it: `$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080 -X POST -d "asd"`, It return me `ASD`

that meaning work ok.

### Debug with inspector:

But when I use `node inspector` to debug my program: `$ node-debug http_uppercaserer.js 8080`,
and test it: `$ curl 127.0.0.1:8080 -X POST -d "asd"`,

It return me:`Cannot POST /`

### Weird

After run `node-debug http_uppercaserer.js 8080`, the default break at first line, when I click resume, the terminal will throw me an error:

```
$ node-debug http_uppercaserer.js 8080
Node Inspector is now available from http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
Debugging `http_uppercaserer.js`

debugger listening on port 5858

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tangmonk/Documents/learn/nodejs_study/async_and_http/http_uppercaserer.js:12:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)
```

But when If I specify port `$ node-debug -p 9000 http_uppercaserer.js 8080`, it works ok, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`node-debug` will by default add `--debug-brk` option which will break the code execution on first line. You would have to resume it. So after doing:

```
node-debug -p 8082 e.js 8081
```

Open the link in chrome and resume execution before running curl. Or you can do it like this:

```
node-inspector  --web-port=8082
node --debug=5858 /datastorage/rupayan/e.js 8081
```

then you can normally do

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8081 -X POST -d "asd"
```

PS: sorry for confusion I cant run my node-inspector on default 8080. So no need to give 8082, if you can use 8080 port.

**Wierd part answer**

That is because node-inspector itself hosts a server and the default address for that is 8080. So both your application and node-inspector cannot use it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, You misunderstood, my program expect a port argument form command line, instead of change the ```node_debug's``` port

Comment: Thanks, your solution works! but I am be weird, I update my question(the ```weird``` section), can you help me again?